# raiz cuadrada en javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola me mandaron este ejercicio y no tengo muy clara la solucion

Un número cuadrado perfecto en matemáticas es un número entero que es el cuadrado de algún otro;
dicho de otro modo, es un número cuya raíz cuadrada es un número natural.
Por ejemplo 49 es un cuadrado perfecto de 7 porque 7 x 7 = 49, o 81 porque 9 x 9 = 81
Pasado por argumento un número, escribe una función la cual devuelva True si el número es un
cuadrado perfecto y False si no lo es.

```js
var mostrar = prompt("introduce un numero"); 
var resultado = Math.sqrt(mostrar);
console.log(resultado)
```

mi pregunta es que logica o que planteamiento debo seguir para resolverlo
gracias

Comment: Creo que debo usar un if y un else cierto?

Comment: que intentastes? solo deberias validar si te devuelve un decimal

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento, ya realizaste alguna investigación previa. Te dejo los siguientes enlaces para que mejores tu pregunta. Evita los negativos e incluso el cierre de tu pregunta. [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878). De paso Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: puedes usar la [funcion isInteger](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/isInteger)

Comment: var mostrar = prompt("introduce un numero");
var resultado = Math.sqrt(mostrar);

console.log(resultado)

Comment: de momento llevo eso hecho me falta que devuelva true y false

Comment: Math.sqrt(numero)%1==0 devuelve true o false

Comment: Hola, @DanielCrespo para añadir información a la pregunta (como tu código, errores, etc), usa el enlace `editar` que está debajo del texto de tu pregunta.

Comment: @DanielCrespo deberias agregar tu ejemplo para la proxima

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer algo como esto, primero solicitas un número, si es igual a 0 o no es un número te volverá a pedirlo, cuando ya hayas ingresado un número le hará la raíz cuadrada, después a ese resultado le sacaremos el residuo, si es igual a 0, es porque es un entero, si no es un flotante, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
let num = prompt('ingresa un numero');

while(isNaN(num) || num == 0){

num = prompt('ingresa un numero');

}

let raiz = Math.sqrt(num);

if(raiz % 1 === 0){
  console.log('Raiz cuadrada perfecta');
}else{

console.log('no lo es');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Un número cuadrado perfecto en matemáticas es un número entero que es el cuadrado de algún otro; dicho de otro modo, es un número cuya raíz cuadrada es un número natural. Por ejemplo 49 es un cuadrado perfecto de 7 porque 7 x 7 = 49, o 81 porque 9 x 9 = 81 Pasado por argumento un número, escribe una función la cual devuelva True si el número es un cuadrado perfecto y False si no lo es.

Para ser cuadrado perfecto entonces tiene que cumplir una condición:

1. Su raiz cuadrada es un número natural.

Un número natural es un número positivo entero: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5...)

Tu función tan solo necesita:

1. Sacar la raiz cuadrada del parámetro que recibe.
2. Comprobar que es un número entero. Si lo es, entonces devuelve `true`. Si no, devuelve `false`.

Por no hacerte todo el ejercicio... en pseudocódigo sería algo así:

```
function esCuadradoPerfecto(numero) {
    var valorRaizCuadrada = raizCuadrada(numero); // Sacar raiz cuadrada.

    return esEntero(valorRaizCuadrada); // Comprobar que sea entero.
}
```

Aquí documentación de una función para sacar la raíz cuadrada [Math.sqrt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/sqrt), y aquí una función para comprobar si un número es entero [Number.isInteger()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/isInteger)

Comment: La "condición" que pones no es correcta. Tal como lo has escrito, estás definiendo lo que sería una "cuarta potencia perfecta", al requerir que su raiz sea a su vez un cuadrado. Por otro lado para que la respuesta sea más útil podrías dar alguna pista de cómo podría funcionar `esEntero()`.

Comment: Gracias por responder, y por las ganas de apoyar. Sin embargo, la pregunta tiene deficiencias y responder preguntas así no contribuyen mucho con el sitio. Además, como @abulafia menciona, tienes un error en tu código. Saludos

Comment: Tenía un error en la condición que escribí. El código está bien.

Answer (score 0):

Después de calcular la raiz cuadrada verifica si la multiplicación de ese resultado al cuadrado es igual que el número introducido:

```
var n = parseInt(prompt("introduce un numero")); 
var resultado = Math.sqrt(n);
if ( resultado * resultado === n ) {
   console.log('El número ingresado es un cuadrado perfecto');
} else {
   console.log('El número ingresado NO es un cuadrado perfecto');
}
```